# Check if a string is a palindrome after whitespace is deleted

Tags: python, python-3.x, palindrome

```
def is_palindrome(input_string):
    # We'll create two strings, to compare them
    new_string = input_string.strip()
    print(new_string)
    # Traverse through each letter of the input string
    newstringseperated = new_string.split()
    n = len(new_string)

    if n%2 == 0:
        for i in range(n//2 - 1):
            if newstringseperated[i] != newstringseperated[n-1-i]:
                print("False")
                hello = 1
    
        if hello == 1:
            print("False")
        else:
            print("True")
    
    
    if (n%2) != 0:
        for i in range((n-1)//2):
            if newstringseperated[i] != newstringseperated[n-1-i]:
                hello2 = 1
    
        if hello2 == 1:
            print("False")
        else: 
            print("True")
```

I tried to execute this code on the words "kayak" and "deed".
It is showing index error for both of them. What is the problem here? Can someone help me find the mistake?

Comment: Right. Changed float to int and ran the code. Index error is the problem

Comment: By whitespace deleted do you mean all white space in the string or just at either end?  strip() only removes whitespace at the ends.

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of problems here.  As @John says, you want to use `n // 2 - 1` rather than `n / 2 - 1` so that the result is an integer.  If you use `re.sub()` instead of `split()`, you can get rid of whitespace in the middle of your input strings and get rid of tabs as well as spaces.  The big issue is that splitting the input string to create `newstringseperated` and using that is messing you up.  If you instead operate on `new_string` directly, your code will work.  Another small detail...you can `break` as soon as you recognize a mismatch.  This version of your code does what I think you're expecting:

```
import re

def is_palindrome(input_string):
    # We'll create two strings, to compare them
    new_string = re.sub(r'\s+', '', input_string)
    print(new_string)
    # Traverse through each letter of the input string
    # newstringseperated = new_string.split()
    n = len(new_string)

    if n % 2 == 0:
        hello = 0
        for i in range(n // 2 - 1):
            if new_string[i] != new_string[n - 1 - i]:
                hello = 1
                break

        if hello == 1:
            print("False")
        else:
            print("True")

        # Add any non-blank letters to the
        # end of one string, and to the front
        # of the other string.

    if (n % 2) != 0:
        hello2 = 0
        for i in range((n - 1) // 2):
            if new_string[i] != new_string[n - 1 - i]:
                hello2 = 1
                break

        if hello2 == 1:
            print("False")
        else:
            print("True")

is_palindrome("kayak")
is_palindrome("deed")
is_palindrome("abcde")
is_palindrome("abcd")
```

Result:

```
kayak
True
deed
True
abcde
False
abcd
False
```

It is better to not have the two cases (odd vs even lengths) in your code.  Here's a way to have just one version of your inner logic:

```
import re

def is_palindrome(input_string):
    new_string = re.sub(r'\s+', '', input_string)
    print(new_string)

    # Traverse through each letter of the input string
    n = len(new_string)
    for i in range(n // 2 - 1 + n % 2):
        if new_string[i] != new_string[n - 1 - i]:
            hello = 1
            break
    else:
        hello = 0

    print("False" if hello == 1 else "True")
```

This produces the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Just reverse the string and test so no looping needed:

```
def is_palindrome(txt):
    txt = txt.replace(' ', '')
    return txt == txt[::-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to delete whitespaces, use `replace()` instead of `strip()` as it takes care of whitespaces in the middle of the string as well.

Secondly, the bigger problem is the `split()` method. It creates a list of substrings based on a specific separator and what you are essentially doing is comparing words instead of characters. Honestly, you don't even need this method to check for palindrome, just modifying the code a bit like this should work fine:

```
def is_palindrome(input_string):
    new_string = input_string.replace(" ", "")

    n = len(new_string)
    for i in range(n // 2):
        if new_string[i] != new_string[n - 1 - i]:
            print("False")
            return False
    print("True")
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this on my phone but this should work if your looking for a palindrome:

```
txt = "hannah"
txt2 = "kayak"
txt3 = "blaat"

def palin(txt):
    first_half = len(txt) // 2
    start_second_half = first_half -1 if len(txt)%2==0 else first_half
    return txt[:first_half] == txt[-1:start_second_half:-1]

print(palin(txt))
print(palin(txt2))
print(palin(txt3))
```